Пытаюсь установить Ruby on Rails через RVM, НО установка заканчивается ошибкой
Ошибка:
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /home/nessie27/.rvm/log/1722012394_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Могу предоставить файл с логами
Операционная система Ubuntu 24.04

Цитату с ошибками из файла логов надо добавить к вопросу, тогда гораздо больше шансов получить ответ

Все просто, установи rails не как apt, а как gem. sudo gem install rails -v[версия]
